# set text in EditText from database

Tags: android, sqlite

I want to display content of a column of a record in a EditText . So to achieve this I made this function in my adapter to get a unqiue row cooresponding to a ID +Name pair

```
public Cursor queryNotes(int lectureID,String user){
    String[] columns = new String[]{KEY_ID,USERNAME,LECTURE_NAME, LECTURE_DATE,LECTURE_NOTES};

    Cursor cursor = sqLiteDatabase.query(MYDATABASE_TABLE,columns ,
            KEY_ID+"=? AND "+USERNAME+"=?" , new String[] { String.valueOf(lectureID),String.valueOf(user) }, null, null, null,null);
    return cursor;
}
```

Then in my fragment class where i want to set the text i did something like this :

```
cursor = mySQLiteAdapter.queryNotes(position,name);
    cursor.moveToPosition(0); 
    if(cursor!=null) { 
        do { 
            String previousNotes = cursor.getString(4); 
            shortnotes.setText(previousNotes);//I assume shortnotes is the EditText I want to set
    }while(cursor.moveToNext());
}
   cursor.close();
```

Is this the right way to set the Edit text?Please help me

Logcat :

> 11-04 17:46:27.141: E/AndroidRuntime(9154): in writeCrashedAppName, pkgName :com.example.loginphase
>   11-04 17:46:27.141: D/AndroidRuntime(9154): file written successfully with content: com.example.loginphase StringBuffer : ;com.example.loginphase
>   11-04 17:46:27.141: E/AndroidRuntime(9154): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
>   11-04 17:46:27.141: E/AndroidRuntime(9154): Process: com.example.loginphase, PID: 9154
>   11-04 17:46:27.141: E/AndroidRuntime(9154): android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: no such column: LECTURE_NOTES (code 1): , while compiling: SELECT _id, USERNAME, LECTURE_NAME, LECTURE_DATE, LECTURE_NOTES FROM LECTURE_TABLE WHERE _id=? AND USERNAME=?
>   11-04 17:46:27.141: E/AndroidRuntime(9154):     at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.nativePrepareStatement(Native Method)
>   11-04 17:46:27.141: E/AndroidRuntime(9154):     at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.acquirePreparedStatement(SQLiteConnection.java:889)
>   11-04 17:46:27.141: E/AndroidRuntime(9154):     at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.prepare(SQLiteConnection.java:500)
>   11-04 17:46:27.141: E/AndroidRuntime(9154):     at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteSession.prepare(SQLiteSession.java:588)
>   11-04 17:46:27.141: E/AndroidRuntime(9154):     at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteProgram.(SQLiteProgram.java:58)
>   11-04 17:46:27.141: E/AndroidRuntime(9154):     at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteQuery.(SQLiteQuery.java:37)
>   11-04 17:46:27.141: E/AndroidRuntime(9154):     at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDirectCursorDriver.query(SQLiteDirectCursorDriver.java:44)
>   11-04 17:46:27.141: E/AndroidRuntime(9154):     at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.rawQueryWithFactory(SQLiteDatabase.java:1314)
>   11-04 17:46:27.141: E/AndroidRuntime(9154):     at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.queryWithFactory(SQLiteDatabase.java:1161)
>   11-04 17:46:27.141: E/AndroidRuntime(9154):     at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.query(SQLiteDatabase.java:1032)
>   11-04 17:46:27.141: E/AndroidRuntime(9154):     at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.query(SQLiteDatabase.java:1238)
>   11-04 17:46:27.141: E/AndroidRuntime(9154):     at database.LecturesDatabaseAdapter.queryNotes(LecturesDatabaseAdapter.java:83)
>   11-04 17:46:27.141: E/AndroidRuntime(9154):     at com.example.loginphase.RecordLectureFragment.onCreateView(RecordLectureFragment.java:34)
>   11-04 17:46:27.141: E/AndroidRuntime(9154):     at android.app.Fragment.performCreateView(Fragment.java:1700)
>   11-04 17:46:27.141: E/AndroidRuntime(9154):     at android.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:890)
>   11-04 17:46:27.141: E/AndroidRuntime(9154):     at android.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1062)
>   11-04 17:46:27.141: E/AndroidRuntime(9154):     at android.app.BackStackRecord.run(BackStackRecord.java:684)
>   11-04 17:46:27.141: E/AndroidRuntime(9154):     at android.app.FragmentManagerImpl.execPendingActions(FragmentManager.java:1447)
>   11-04 17:46:27.141: E/AndroidRuntime(9154):     at android.app.FragmentManagerImpl$1.run(FragmentManager.java:443)
>   11-04 17:46:27.141: E/AndroidRuntime(9154):     at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:733)
>   11-04 17:46:27.141: E/AndroidRuntime(9154):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
>   11-04 17:46:27.141: E/AndroidRuntime(9154):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
>   11-04 17:46:27.141: E/AndroidRuntime(9154):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5021)
>   11-04 17:46:27.141: E/AndroidRuntime(9154):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
>   11-04 17:46:27.141: E/AndroidRuntime(9154):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
>   11-04 17:46:27.141: E/AndroidRuntime(9154):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:827)
>   11-04 17:46:27.141: E/AndroidRuntime(9154):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:643)
>   11-04 17:46:27.141: E/AndroidRuntime(9154):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)

Here is my helper class for database :

```
 public class LectureDatabaseHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper {
 public static final String MYDATABASE_NAME = "LECTURE_DATABASE";
 public static final String MYDATABASE_TABLE = "LECTURE_TABLE";
 public static final int MYDATABASE_VERSION = 2;
 public static final String KEY_ID = "_id";
 public static final String USERNAME = "USERNAME";
 public static final String LECTURE_NAME = "LECTURE_NAME";
 public static final String LECTURE_DATE = "LECTURE_DATE";
 public static final String LECTURE_NOTES = "LECTURE_NOTES";
 private static final String SCRIPT_CREATE_DATABASE =
          "create table " + MYDATABASE_TABLE + " ("
          + KEY_ID + " integer primary key autoincrement, "
          + USERNAME + " text not null, "
          + LECTURE_NAME + " text not null, "
          + LECTURE_DATE + " text not null, "
          + LECTURE_NOTES + " text null);";
  public LectureDatabaseHelper(Context context, String name,
    CursorFactory factory, int version) {
   super(context, name, factory, version);
  }
  public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
   db.execSQL(SCRIPT_CREATE_DATABASE);
  }
  public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
    db.execSQL("DROP TABLE "+MYDATABASE_TABLE+";");
    onCreate(db);
  }
 }
```

Comment: What is the problem?

Comment: @PedroOliveira My application is crasing abruptly when I open this fragment

Comment: Then start by showing us your logcat

Comment: @PedroOliveira  I attached the logcat

Comment: `no such column: LECTURE_NOTES`

Answer (score 0):

```
        public String getuserid() {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

           // write this method in dbhelper class
            SQLiteDatabase db = null;
            String selectQuery = "SELECT KEY_ID,USERNAME,LECTURE_NAME,LECTURE_DATE,LECTURE_NOTES FROM yourtable";
            StringBuilder sb= new StringBuilder();

            try {
                db = this.getWritableDatabase();
                Cursor cursor1 = db.rawQuery(selectQuery, null);
                while (cursor1.moveToNext()) {
                String KEY_ID= cursor1.getString(cursor1.getColumnIndex("KEY_ID"));
sb.append(KEY_ID);
sb.append("-");
                String USERNAME= cursor1.getString(cursor1.getColumnIndex("USERNAME"));
sb.append(USERNAME);
sb.append("-");
                String LECTURE_NAME=cursor1.getString(cursor1.getColumnIndex("LECTURE_NAME"));
sb.append(LECTURE_NAME);
sb.append("-");
                String LECTURE_NOTES = cursor1.getString(cursor1.getColumnIndex("LECTURE_NOTES "));
  sb.append(LECTURE_NOTES );

                }

            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

            return sb;
        }



----------


    Call Above method  for fetching Data from DBSqlite

    String mtext=dbhelperobject.getuserid();
    if(mtext!=null)
    {
    yourtextview.settext(mtext)
    }
```

Comment: Hey Why are you fetching all records from Database ?My database table LECTURE_TABLE  has following fields :KEY_ID,USERNAME,LECTURE_NAME, LECTURE_DATE,LECTURE_NOTES. And i want only that record that has unique pair of KEY_ID,USERNAME

Comment: check again i hav made some changes

Answer (score 0):

I recomend U make something like this

```
public String queryNotes(int lectureID,String user){
    String[] columns = new String[]{KEY_ID,USERNAME,LECTURE_NAME, LECTURE_DATE,LECTURE_NOTES};

    Cursor cursor = sqLiteDatabase.query(MYDATABASE_TABLE,columns ,
            KEY_ID+"=? AND "+USERNAME+"=?" , new String[] {   String.valueOf(lectureID),String.valueOf(user) }, null, null, null,null);
    StringBuilder sb=new StringBuilder();
    while (cursor.moveToNext()) {
     ab.append(cursor.getString(4)));
    }
    cursor.close();
    return sb.toString();
}
```

Comment: Also tell me how to update the table on click of a save Button with new string in the EditField

Comment: Add method to adapter like `code` public boolean `updateNotes(String note, int lectureID, String user) { ... }`

Comment: Are you sure above method in answer is right ?It still crashes

Comment: provide logcat please

Comment: I attached logcat details

Comment: Your table _LECTURE_TABLE_ do not contain _LECTURE_NOTES_ field. Check, what fields name during table  creation.

Comment: This is create statement  "create table " + MYDATABASE_TABLE + " ("
     + KEY_ID + " integer primary key autoincrement, "
     + USERNAME + " text not null, "
     + LECTURE_NAME + " text not null, "
     + LECTURE_DATE + " text not null, "
     + LECTURE_NOTES + " text null);";

Comment: **Smu : "Can you please write the update function ?"** As I understand reading now works? :)

Answer (score 0):

The error is quite easy to spot once you read the logcat.

> no such column: LECTURE_NOTES (code 1): , while compiling: SELECT _id,
>   USERNAME, LECTURE_NAME, LECTURE_DATE, LECTURE_NOTES FROM LECTURE_TABLE
>   WHERE _id=? AND USERNAME=?

You don't have any column with the name `LECTURE_NOTES`. Make sure you write it correctly by checking your `CREATE TABLE` query

If you edited your database lately make sure you uninstall your application or change the database version so you can force the creation of the new database

Comment: See my Database Helper It has named of column with LECTURE_NOTES in create statement

Comment: Like I said. The error you posted is for that. Try uninstalling your apk and try again.

Comment: Yeah it worked...:) Can you please write update function for it also ?

Comment: This not a place to ask for functions. There are plenty tutorials on the internet of how to write an update function. If this solved your problem remember to mark it as answer. Have a nice day